# Java Scan for a keywords following word

Tags: java, string, input, keyword

I am going for a pretty specific problem:

- working with java and eclipse
- got a buch of characters in a long String (words, brackets, question marks etc.)
- trying to sort the incoming information for further progress by keywords

So what i try is:

1. take the incoming string, which is like *"we got a new member. he's name is: Peter. He is pretty nice. he is a member of the group: devceloper. Also he's birthday is: 13.08.2001. As well we got a new member*...
2. scan the string for some keywords, which will follow in a specific order, like "name", "group" and "birthday"
3. recognize the keyword, the "non-needed" following characters (which are the same every time)
4. extract the relevant information and put it in a 2-dimensional array.
   so my output should look like 
   {{"peter", "developer", "13.08.2001"}, {"susan", "marketing", "02.03.1997"}...}

To complete this, i found a basic script, which should "extract" separate words, but it is still buggy, so it's not really helpful.

```
int indexOfSpace = 0; 
int nextIndexOfSpace = 0;

String sentence = "This is a sentence";

int lastIndexOfSpace = sentence.lastIndexOf(" "); 
while(indexOfSpace != lastIndexOfSpace) { 
    nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace);
    String word = sentence.substring(indexOfSpace,nextIndexOfSpace);
    System.out.println("Word: " + word + " Length: " + word.length());
    indexOfSpace = nextIndexOfSpace; }

String lastWord = sentence.substring(lastIndexOfSpace);
System.out.println("Word: " + lastWord + " Length: " + lastWord.length());
```

I'm not expectigt you to give me the ready-to-go solution, but i could need some hints for programming steps ;)

Comment: If you want "some hints" then SO is not for you. This is a pure Q/A forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regular expression similar to this one:

```
name[^:]*:\s*(\w+).*?group[^:]*:\s*(\w+).*?birthday[^:]*:\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

For input string:

> we got a new member. he's name is: Peter. He is pretty nice. he is a member of the group: devceloper. Also he's birthday is: 13.08.2001. As well we got a new member...

It would capture the following groups:

- Peter
- devceloper
- 13.08.2001

Using a matcher for the pattern, you can iterate all matches.

Example code:

```
String input = "we got a new member. he's name is: Peter. He is pretty nice. he "
            + "is a member of the group: devceloper. Also he's birthday is: 13.08.2001."
            + " As well we got a new member she's name is: Sara. She is pretty nice. "
            + "she is a member of the group: customer. Also her birthday is: 21.01.1998";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name[^:]*:\\s*(\\w+).*?group[^:]*:\\s*(\\w+).*?birthday[^:]*:\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Match found. name: %s, group: %s, birthday: %s %n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
Match found. name: Peter, group: devceloper, birthday: 13.08.2001 
Match found. name: Sara, group: customer, birthday: 21.01.1998
```

Comment: But there are several information "banks" following in the same String. How i keep track on where i stopped, when there are like 10 people mentioned in the text, which is saved in the String? I would need to extract one information by the other and then continue "reading" the String at the lastz stopped point

Comment: The matcher takes care of matching the input string for more matches of the regular expression

Comment: wow ... ty very mauch :)
earlier i would have tried to scan the string for characters and tried to write letter-by-letter in a new string and writin this string into the array. This way it is so much easier...

Comment: So i tried to adopt the code to my project.
My input now looks like:
`"name":"peter", "group":" developer", "age":"17" .... (some bunch of other information) ... "name":"Sara", "group"` ...`
and my code snipplet looks like:
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*name\":\"(\\w+).*group\":\"(\\w+).*age\":\"(\\w+).*");

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
  while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.printf("name: %s, group %s, age %s %n", 
     matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
  }`
But the output gives me only the information of the last person and stops :/

Comment: @renegade2k beware of the greedy `.*`, use the lazy version `.*?` otherwise they would consume the entire remaining string

Comment: Great! This fixed it. At the moment i dont understand why, but it works now. I will keep on it to understand what happend there to not make same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the string will always follow the same form, you can implement a regexp match. The idea is to use groups to capture the substring that you are interested in.

For instance you can use `.*name is: (\w+)` to capture `Peter` from your string. Similarly you can apply it to the other tokens.

Comment: the string is always repeating and follows the same structure. The only variation is that some information is just absent (kinda "birthday: []"), so í need to fill the gaps with just a space or null or something like this, cause i will use the array to show a table afterwards